# How to call API in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express

I have these API calls which I need to do in my AngularJS controller.

Any example will be helpful.

```
app.post('/user/auth', users.auth);
app.get('/user/logout', helpers.isAuthenticated, users.logout);
```

Comment: What are the name of the `helpers.isAuthenticated` and `users.logout` parameters which the api is expecting?

Comment: Thanks for the help, you can find all the details here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728872/authenticating-user-from-api-to-angular-js

Comment: So, you post another question which is an "extended" version of this one? You could have edited this (There was no need to post another one).

Comment: I first put a full question but no one responded so i break it down to understand things one by one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to make use of the [`$http` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) like this:

```
angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('ctrlname', ['$http', function($http){

    //POST sample
    $http.post('/user/auth', users.auth).then(function(response){
         //handle your response here
    });

    //GET sample
    //substitute 'param1' and 'param2' for the proper name the API is expecting these parameters
    $http.get('/user/logout/?param1=' + helpers.isAuthenticated + '&param2=' + users.logout).then(function(response){
         //handle your response here
    });

   }]
);
```