# Nodejs api call from angular2 service

Tags: node.js, angular

I have node api that returns data to browser using this api :

```
app.get('/api/patients',function(req,res){
    Patient.getPatients(function(err,patients){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(patients.length);
        res.json(patients);

    });
});
```

I am trying to call this api from the service class.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../patient.interface';



@Injectable()
export class PatientDataService {

    patients : Patient[] =[];


    constructor() { }



    getAllPatients(): Patient[]
    {
          // What to do here ??
    }

}
```

How do i return data from node api to service ?

Comment: i think the above code is from angular2

Comment: @PankajParkar This is an Angular 2 application, not an AngularJS (1) application.

Comment: [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and something related (but AngularJS 1) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729837/how-to-call-api-in-angular-controller/42729971#42729971)

Comment: My bad.. didn't looked at Angular 2 tag.. though its would be same as `http.get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
@Injectable()
export class PatientDataService {

    patients : Patient[] =[];


    constructor(private http:Http) { }


        getAllPatients()
         {
          return this.http.get('base_url/api/people').map((res)=>res.json());

        }

}
```

and in your component inject this service and call

```
this.patientService.getAllPatients().subscribe((data)=>{
   //data is your patient list
})
```

Comment: thank you .. this helped but now I am getting following error in browser console:  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/patients. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: i fixed it by adding CORS in node api : app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

Comment: @DevHelp, you're making a call from an AngularJS application on one domain to your web server on another domain. Have you properly configured CORS on your web-server?

Comment: @DevHelp, never mind -- you beat me to it :) just be careful in any kind of production app using "*", this means any app on any domain can make a call to your web server.

Comment: Thanks Ben . How do I make sure to only allow some domains to access this service ?

Answer (score 2):

You can first import the Angular2 Http library into your service:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

I also import rx/js for use of Observables and mapping.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

You can then inject the library into your service:

```
constructor(private _http: Http) { }
```

Make your http call to your node.js server like this:

```
getAllPatients(): Patient[]
{
      // What to do here ??
      return this._http.get('/api/patients')
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

For more information, documentation, and clarification please read the [Angular 2 Http Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#http-providers)